# How to scroll Flow layout panel content as per mouse position

Tags: c#, winforms

i have taken one Flow layout panel and placed multiple picture box inside in it. now i want when i will place my mouse at the right or left most edge of the Flow layout panel then rest of picture will scroll out. just think about windows 8 start screen where many tiles appear in screen and when we place mouse at right most edge on the screen then rest of the tiles scroll out. i want to simulate same thing in windows form with Flow layout panel.

i want my Flow layout panel will not show scroll bar but images will scroll out when i will place mouse right or left most part on the panel. here is my screen shot
[image]

some one told me to do it this way...here is bit code
**Set AutoScrollPosition property in MouseMove event of Panel.**

```
private void panel1_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    panel1.AutoScrollPosition = new Point(e.X, e.Y);
}
```

but this trick was not good. AutoScrollPosition works when scroll bar is visible but in my case i do not want to show scroll bar with Flow layout panel. i want smooth scrolling images from left to right or right to left. anyone can help me to achieve what i am trying to do....if possible guide me with respect of coding. thanks

### EDIT

Here i am giving my full code after modification following @Taw suggestion but it is not working fine....rather flickering found when picture move. anyway here is the full code.

```
namespace ScrollTest
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            flowLayoutPanel1.MouseMove += MouseScroll;

            foreach (Control x in this.Controls)
            {
                if (x is PictureBox)
                {
                    ((PictureBox)x).MouseMove += MouseScroll;         
                }
            }
        }

        int near = 33;
        private void MouseScroll(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            Point mouse = flowLayoutPanel1.PointToClient(MousePosition);
            Rectangle C = flowLayoutPanel1.ClientRectangle;

            int dLeft = mouse.X - C.Left;
            int dTop = mouse.Y - C.Top;
            int dRight = C.Right - mouse.X;
            int dBottom = C.Bottom - mouse.Y;

            int dX = dLeft < near ? dLeft : dRight < near ? -dRight : 0;
            int dY = dTop < near ? dTop : dBottom < near ? -dBottom : 0;

            if (dX != 0 | dY != 0) scrollFLP(dX, dY);
        }

        void scrollFLP(int deltaX, int deltaY)
        {
            flowLayoutPanel1.Left += getSpeedFromDistance(deltaX);
            flowLayoutPanel1.Top += getSpeedFromDistance(deltaY);
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(11);
        }

        int getSpeedFromDistance(int delta)
        {
            int sig = Math.Sign(delta);
            int d = Math.Abs(delta);
            if (d > near / 2) return sig;
            else if (d > near / 3) return near / 10 * sig;
            else if (d > near / 4) return near / 8 * sig;
            else if (d > near / 5) return near / 5 * sig;
            else return near * sig;
        }
    }
}
```

basically i am trying achieve something like suppose i have `flow layout panel` and which has many picture box inside it with many images as the screen shot but scroll bar should not show rather scroll will happen automatically when i will place my mouse at the top or bottom of the flow layout panel like `carousel`.

see this picture of your application
[image]

when place my mouse at the right end then it scroll and form background shown which i do not want. i want picture box will scroll & scroll upto last one not more than that.

any idea how to do it. thanks

### 2nd Edit

[image]

this code i added as per your suggestion

```
public Form1()
            {
                InitializeComponent();

                for (int i = 0; i < 666; i++)
                {
                    PictureBox pan = new PictureBox();
                    //pan.MouseMove += MouseScroll;
                    //pan.MouseLeave += outSideCheck;
                    pan.Size = new Size(75, 75);
                    pan.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(255, (i * 2) & 255, (i * 7) & 255, (i * 4) & 255);
                    flowLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(pan);

                }
                //flowLayoutPanel1.MouseMove += MouseScroll;
                //this.flowLayoutPanel1.MouseLeave += outSideCheck;

                mouseScroller MSC = new mouseScroller();
                MSC.registerControl(flowLayoutPanel1);  // FLP = your FlowLayouPanel
                MSC.timerSpeed = 5;  // optional
                MSC.nearness = 100;  // optional

                flowLayoutPanel1.AutoScroll = false;

            }
```

now the apps doing wired behavior after adding new code. if i am making any mistake then guide me please. thanks

Comment: What you mean is you have pictureboxes that are not visible and want to scroll them in?

Comment: my flow layout panel has many picture boxes like picture attached and all are not visible. so i want to scroll the flow layout panel automatically when i will place my mouse at the bottom edge of the flow layout panel or top edge of flow layout panel. am i clear...still if not then ask me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a two-part problem:

- How to grab the event
- How to scroll a `FlowLayoutPanel` with its scrollbars invisible.

Second first. It is not an easy task from what I found, unless you use a simple and rather common trick: Don't actually scroll it! Instead place it into a `Panel` and then control its position inside that `Panel`.

To do this you add a `Panel panel1` to your Form, `Dock` or `Anchor` it as you need to and set its `Autoscroll = false` (!) (Which is not the way it is usually done, when you want to make, say a `PictureBox` scrollable. But we don't want the `Panel` to show it `Scrollbars` either.)

Set the FLP to its desired size and place it into the Panel, it obviously also has `Autoscroll = false`, and we're ready to tackle the other problem of setting up the event..:

First you add the  `MouseScroll` event below to your code and then you hook every control up to it you want to work with the mouse move, namely the FLP:

```
  flowLayoutPanel1.MouseMove += MouseScroll;
```

..and also each of your PictureBoxes, maybe like this

```
  // your creation loop..
  PictureBox pbox = new PictureBox();
  pbox.MouseMove += MouseScroll;           // <<--- hook into to the mousemove
  pan.MouseLeave += outSideCheck;          // <<--- hook into to the mouseleave

  // .. do your stuff.. here I put some paint on to test..
  pbox.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(255, 111, (i * 3) & 255, (i * 4) & 255);
  flowLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(pbox);
```

or however you create them..

**Edit 2** I have changed my original code once more. It now includes an outside check, a check for moving towards the closest edge and a workaround for tha mousemove bug. It uses a Timer set to maybe 30ms. The speed mapping is in a function of its own.

```
 flowLayoutPanel1.MouseMove += MouseScroll;
 this.flowLayoutPanel1.MouseLeave += outSideCheck;
 flowLayoutPanel1.AutoScroll = false;


int near = 33;
Point lastLocation = Point.Empty;
int dX = 0;
int dY = 0;

private void MouseScroll(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    Point  mouse = panel1.PointToClient(MousePosition);
    Rectangle C = panel1.ClientRectangle;
    // mouseMove has a bug, we need to workaround
    if (mouse == lastLocation) return;
    if (lastLocation == Point.Empty) { lastLocation = mouse; return; }


    // distance from each edge
    int dLeft = mouse.X - C.Left;
    int dTop = mouse.Y - C.Top;
    int dRight = C.Right - mouse.X;
    int dBottom = C.Bottom - mouse.Y;

    // relevant distances with sign
        dX = dLeft < near ? dLeft : dRight < near ? -dRight : 0;
        dY = dTop < near ? dTop : dBottom < near ? -dBottom : 0;

        // we need the closest edge to check if we are moving in or out
    List<int> edges = new List<int>() { dLeft, dTop, dRight, dBottom };
    var closest = edges.IndexOf(edges.Min());

    // if we are moving
    if (dX != 0 | dY != 0)
        // if moving out: go else stop going
        if (!movingIn(mouse, closest)) timer1.Start(); else timer1.Stop();
    // remember position    
    lastLocation = mouse;
}

bool movingIn(Point current, int Edge)
{
    switch (Edge)
    {
        case 0:  return current.X > lastLocation.X;
        case 1:  return current.Y > lastLocation.Y;
        case 2:  return current.X < lastLocation.X;
        case 3:  return current.Y < lastLocation.Y;
    }
    return false;
}

void scrollFLP(int deltaX, int deltaY)
{
    flowLayoutPanel1.Left += getSpeedFromDistance(deltaX);
    flowLayoutPanel1.Top += getSpeedFromDistance(deltaY);
    Size C = panel1.ClientSize;
    if (flowLayoutPanel1.Left > 1) { flowLayoutPanel1.Left = 0; timer1.Stop(); }
    if (flowLayoutPanel1.Right < C.Width) 
        { flowLayoutPanel1.Left = C.Width - flowLayoutPanel1.Width; timer1.Stop(); }
    if (flowLayoutPanel1.Top > 1) { flowLayoutPanel1.Top = 0; timer1.Stop(); }
    if (flowLayoutPanel1.Bottom < C.Height) 
        { flowLayoutPanel1.Top = C.Height - flowLayoutPanel1.Height; timer1.Stop(); }
}

int getSpeedFromDistance(int delta)
{
    int sig = Math.Sign(delta); 
    int d = Math.Abs(delta);
    if (d > near / 2) return  sig;
    else if (d > near / 3) return 2 * sig;
    else if (d > near / 4) return 4 * sig;
    else if (d > near / 5) return 6 * sig;
    else return 10 * sig;
}

private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)  
{
        if (insidePanel()) scrollFLP(dX, dY); else timer1.Stop();
    }

bool insidePanel()
{
    return panel1.ClientRectangle.Contains(panel1.PointToClient(MousePosition));
}

private void outSideCheck(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!insidePanel()) {timer1.Stop(); lastLocation = Point.Empty;}
}
```

Of course you'll want to play with the various 'magic' numbers :-)

Stop code and direction check are now included.

As usual, key is to know precisely what you want.. I hope this gets you started on ways to achieve it!

Comment: thanks for your reply but the code you give that did not work as expected. please see my edit for the full code which i test. looking for suggestion. thanks

Comment: hi, I'm pressed for time atm and will look at your post update closer later today. I have just posted my last version which  find greatly improved and scrolling really smoothly. One question though: do you want to scroll left-right or up-down or both? I have implemented both but your post is unclear..

Comment: One note though: _foreach (Control x in this.Controls)_ This seems wrong - are the Pictureboxes really still in this.Controls? After you add them to the FLP they are in its Controls collection! This means that the scrolling happens only for the gaps between them!!

Comment: the logic u gave that is not working. your logic moving the flp container but i want to scroll the images with in flp container when mouse touch the up or down edge of flp container. better write your logic at your end and test then you can understand what problem is occurring.

Comment: My logic works fine and is tested. The __effect__ is precisely what you want even if it is accomplished differently. I doubt that you have implemented it as I suggested, though. Of course you can try to actually scroll the FLP, but I don't know how to do that. Do you?? Without the Scrollbars showing this seems to be next to impossible. If you want I can zip the solution and upload it somewhere, so you can test the version I have..

Comment: Here is the [project](http://www.file-upload.net/download-9539743/Scroller.zip.html) - let me know if it works..

Comment: thanks for uploading project code. i add one pic there and it is working partially.when place my mouse at the right end then it scroll and scroll and at last form background shown which i do not want. i want picture box will scroll & scroll upto last one not more than that.

any idea how to do it. thanks

Comment: Stop code is now included in the answer. Make sure your FLP isn't too large - took me a while to see that mine had an empty part at the bottom.. (which will also be so in the uploaded project!!)

Comment: please click on this link http://i.imgur.com/ZYzVMuV.gif . i want this kind of scrolling & UI with FLP. can u plzz customize your code to have this kind of scrolling. thanks

Comment: Well, that is what my code does. It does, as you asked in the question also scroll up and down. However you may want to wait a little - I'll put up an even nicer version, encapsulated in a single class to CodeReview later today.. All it needs are two lines of code!

Comment: thanks @Taw.....i will be waiting for your code. please upload the new code and give me the link to download it.

Comment: [Here](http://www.file-upload.net/download-9543231/mouseScroller.zip.html) is the scroll controller class. Use it __instead__ of all the code I wrote boefore!

Comment: thanks for your effort. now a weird result comes. if possible get me chance to download your modified code. i attached the current screen shot after adding new class as per your suggestion. see my 2nd edit section.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/61484/discussion-between-taw-and-thomas).

Comment: sorry it worked but some time i saw scrolling is stopped and start again. the scrolling is not very smooth. anyway thanks

Answer (score 0):

It's been a while since this question was asked. I just encountered the problem. My scenario was a little different, but I still think it's a solution to the same problem (at worst a timer control can be used because autoscroll is not turned on).

Here is my scenario: I have one `panel` control (normal panel). I have an `PictureBox` in it that I made with zoom. I'm making rectangular selections on top of this image, and when the selections spilled out of the panel, my panel was supposed to slide in the direction I was selecting. (in my scenario, mouse is pressed)(also in my scenario, autoscroll is on). This is how I solved it without writing so much code:

I added two private variable for scroll position (Valid for the whole class scope).

```
private int xPos;
private int yPos;
private int speed = 5;
```

and I assigned them the current scroll positions when the form is loaded.

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //when I change the scrollbar manually or change with zoom I still 
    //need to add these lines to the related event
    xPos = panel1.HorizontalScroll.Value;
    yPos = panel1.VerticalScroll.Value;
}
```

and inside my picturebox's mousemove event

```
private void picturebox1_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left) {

       Point mouse = panel1.PointToClient(MousePosition);

       if (!panel1.ClientRectangle.Contains( mouse ))
       {
           Rectangle CRect = panel1.ClientRectangle;
           int dLeft = mouse.X - CRect.Left;
           int dRight = CRect.Right - mouse.X;
           int dTop = mouse.Y - CRect.Top;
           int dBottom = CRect.Bottom - mouse.Y;
        
           if(dLeft < 0 && panel1.HorizontalScroll.Value > 0)
           {
               xPos = -panel1.AutoScrollPosition.X - speed;
           }
           if (dRight < 0 && panel1.HorizontalScroll.Value < panel1.HorizontalScroll.Maximum)
           {
               xPos = -panel1.AutoScrollPosition.X + speed;
           }
           if (dTop < 0 && panel1.VerticalScroll.Value > 0)
           {
               yPos = -panel1.AutoScrollPosition.Y - speed;
           }
           if (dBottom < 0 && panel1.VerticalScroll.Value < panel1.VerticalScroll.Maximum)
           {
               yPos = -panel1.AutoScrollPosition.Y + speed;
           }
           panel1.AutoScrollPosition = new Point(xPos, yPos);

       }
   }
}
```